# If $A$ and $B$ are closed sets in $\mathbb{R}$, is $A\times B$ closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If $A$ and $B$ are closed sets in $\mathbb{R}$, is $A\times B$ closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

**My attempt:**

Firstly note that \begin{align}\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus(A\times B) &= (\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R})\setminus (A \times B) \\ &= ((\mathbb{R} \setminus A) \times \mathbb{R})\cup (\mathbb{R} \times (\mathbb{R}\setminus B))\end{align}

Now we know that $(\mathbb{R}\setminus A)$ and $(\mathbb{R}\setminus B)$ are both open.

We also have that $\mathbb{R}$ is both open and closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

How can I continue from here to show that the entire union is open (and hence show that $A \times B$ is closed)?

Comment: The union of open subsets is open.

Comment: $(\mathbb{R} \setminus A) \times \mathbb{R}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$ since a basis for this space is the set of products of open sets

Comment: What's elementary topology?

Comment: @AsafKaragila - I am not sure, our course outline simply says "Elementary Topology in $\mathbb{R}^p$". Under what category of topology would that fall?

Comment: General, or none.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a sequence in $A \times B$ and let it converge. Then, both of its components must converge as well. Since $A$ is closed, the first component converges to a point inside $A$; similarly the second component converges to a point inside $B$. Therefore the sequence converges to a point inside $A \times B$.